# Homebrew: can't remove 'keg-only' OpenSSL application

Tags: macos, homebrew, openssl

Given the recent OpenSSL scare I'm trying to clean out older versions from my machines but Homebrew won't let me:

```
$ brew dirty
openssl (1.0.1e, 1.0.1f, 1.0.1g)
$ brew cleanup openssl
Warning: Skipping (old) keg-only: /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1e
Warning: Skipping (old) keg-only: /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1f
$ brew dirty
openssl (1.0.1e, 1.0.1f, 1.0.1g)
```

How can I purge these old versions of OpenSSL from my Mac?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of Homebrew [f4d2141](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/commit/f4d21415debe6e707b89a55b573b2b2fe5aef35d) there is a `--force` option.

```
brew cleanup --force openssl
```

References: `man brew`

Comment: Ya, but are some applications compiled using the old versions of OpenSSL? And if so what will happen to those applications?!?  Or, better put, what does "keg-only" mean?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17015285/understand-homebrew-and-keg-only-dependencies) and the [FAQ](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/FAQ) for explanations of keg-only packages. If an application is complied against a keg-only package that goes missing, it may very well break. But then, the point of this is that you don't want things linking to openssl < 1.0.1g anyway. Broken is better than insecure.

Comment: Can I identify what other software may be linking to those older libraries?

Comment: You can't query a library to see what is linked against it, but you can do the reverse; inspect a binary to see what it depends on using `otool -L`. In your example though you can safely remove 1.0.1e and 1.0.1f since they both compile to the same library file as 1.0.1g (`libssl-1.0.0.dylib`, which is symlinked to `libssl.dylib`). Put another way, applications aren't linking to a specific point release of libssl. If you've installed 1.0.1g then this should satisfy anything in the brew ecosystem that was depending on 1.0.1(e|f).